# Object with callback block destroyed after init

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have such a helper class.

```
@interface CustomOnScreenshot : NSObject;

@property (copy) void (^finishedCallback)(id sender);

-(instancetype)initWithCallback: (void (^)(id sender))callback;

+(instancetype)onScreenshot:(void (^)(id sender))callback;

@end

@implementation CustomOnScreenshot

-(instancetype)initWithCallback: (void (^)(id sender))callback{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.finishedCallback = callback;
        [self subscribeEvent];
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype)onScreenshot:(void (^)(id sender))callback{
    CustomOnScreenshot * onScreenShot = [self new];
    [onScreenShot setFinishedCallback:callback];
    return onScreenShot;
}

-(void)subscribeEvent{
    NSLog(@"CustomOnScreenshot subscribeEvent");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doOnScreenShot:) name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)unsubscribeEvent{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)doOnScreenShot: (id)sender{
    if (self.finishedCallback) {
        self.finishedCallback(sender);
    }
}

-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"CustomOnScreenshot dealloc");
    [self unsubscribeEvent];
}
```

The problem is that if you use it as intended, then the object is immediately destroyed

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [CustomOnScreenshot onScreenshot:^(id sender) {
        // CUSTOM code
    }];
}
```

Log:
*CustomOnScreenshot subscribeEvent*
*CustomOnScreenshot dealloc*

All works only when I use the result in property, but I find this excessive

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomOnScreenshot * customOnScreenshot;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.customOnScreenshot = [CustomOnScreenshot onScreenshot:^(id sender) {
        // CUSTOM code
    }];
}
```

Comment: You could keep it alive by creating a retain cycle: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef027df9fd18f5b4e6c821299973df16 but I'm not sure I'd recommend that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a strong reference *to* the `CustomOnScreenshot` instance, then the object will be deallocated by ARC as as soon as `+onScreenshot:` finishes execution.

That's why the `@property` fixes it.

If you don't want an `@property`, then I'd suggest a singleton.